# Accessing Vue.$router inside an external "service" class

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a service which extends EventEmitter.

`services/service/service.js` (relative to main.js)

```
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

class Service extends EventEmitter {}
```

Inside the Service class, I have the following method which returns a Promise:

```
  /**
   * Method to fetch the Active Survey by "surveySlug":
   */
  fetchActiveSurvey(serviceSlug) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(`${this.baseURL}/service/${serviceSlug}`, { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } }).then(response => {
        resolve(response.data);
      }).catch(error => {
        if (error.response && error.response.data.status != 200) {
          Vue.$router.push({ name: 'home'});
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

I also have the usual `routes.js` in the same directory as `main.js`, which is working fine.

Services are then established as plugins:

```
import Service from "../services/service/service"; // <= Refrences `service.js`

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$service = Service;
  }
};
```

I have tried the following:

`Vue.$router.push({ name: 'home'});`

`Vue.prototype.$router.push({ name: 'home'});`

However, I seem to find that `$router` is not defined. What would be the best way to define the router push routes from inside this service?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `this` keyword to access the router instance. Try:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'home'});
```

Comment: `this.` inside the service, will not work. `this.` is the Service class. Without sounding rude, I'm not even going to try this. :D

Comment: Can you import the router instance just as you did eventEmitter and call it within service?

Comment: Yeh, possible. I could use `import router from '@/router';` It's the same router instance, right? Or does it really matter?

Comment: Yes, I think that will reference back to the same router instance, since @/router will point to the index.js

Comment: Yeh, worked. Didn’t need this.router.push() tho. Just router.push()